# What other backdoor access to wp-admin login page should I look for?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

I recently started looking more closely at the WordPress Sucuri plugin in and the failed login log files.

To limit the number of attempts at trying to login, I've added an IP whitelist to the WordPress .htaccess file; i.e. any attempts from an IP not in that list trying to access wp-admin will get a 403 error. I've tested this from a few different IPs and looks to be working - the 403 error is showing up and, because the login page doesn't show up, there is no log of the attempt.

However, there are still IPs being logged in the "Failed Login" log that are not in the IP Whitelist.

I have to assume there is some backdoor to the login page that I am not aware of. Ideas on where to look would be appreciated.

Updated: here's what my .htaccess file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
# Access 1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$ 
# Access 2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.5$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you could add the IP whitelist line(s) from your .htaccess file that'd help a lot. It's possible that you're not blocking all available URLs that users can login from.

Comment: you could log in as admin in frontend and navigate using admin bar

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - can you elaborate on where you could login as admin in the frontend? Login links have been removed from the WordPress site. In addition, the login link would redirect to the wp-admin I believe.

Comment: @MHayward - I've updated the post with the example; I believe it covers all urls that might have login access.

Comment: @gateauboeuf that depends on your site set up, I built a module that has it's own log in system so there for me, but if you've removed log in links from frontend then should be ok

Comment: does it also pick up server log in attempts?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - it's not picking up server log in attempts. I'm going to run a scan with a 3rd party tool to see if the site has been compromised.

Comment: do you have any third-party plugins installed? Sometimes these can be a way in (if coded insecurely and incorrectly, and unfortunately, WordPress doesn't enforce the correct way to code modules. so this can happen quite a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research and based on people's responses, it looks like it's either:

1. A backdoor / security issue in one or more plugins
2. Site has been compromised and to look in the themes and database; core files look to be intact based on Sucuri log.

In other words, more investigation needs to be done but I hope this helps other folks from a  next steps perspective.